# Why do mtime and atime need to be updated?

Tags: alluxio

Does anyone know why the mtime and atime need to be updated when completing the file?

```
mInodeTree.updateInode(rpcContext, UpdateInodeEntry.newBuilder()

    .setId(inode.getId())
    .setUfsFingerprint(ufsFingerprint)
    .setLastModificationTimeMs(opTimeMs) // mtime?
    .setLastAccessTimeMs(opTimeMs) // atime?
    .setOverwriteModificationTime(true)
    .build();
mInodeTree.updateInodeFile(rpcContext, entry.build());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the early days when Alluxio is mostly used for Spark or MR for storing really large files, we were thinking the completion could take a while, thus the completion time may better reflect the mtime and atime. I don’t think there is any particular technical reason behind that